# Titanium iOS Simulator (run button greyed out)

Tags: iphone, ios, titanium-mobile

**Info**:

```
Titanium Studio, build: 3.1.0.201304151600
Build: jenkins-titanium-rcp-master-417 (origin/master)
Date: 15 April 2013, 16:04:14

iOS configuration details: iOS SDK is installed correctly!

Xcode: Version 4.6.2 (4H1003)

Mac OS X: v. 10.8.3
```

**Problem description**:

Hello there,

I am trying to configure `Titanium` in order for it to build apps for both `Android 4.x` and `iOS 6.1`. The `Android` part works fine so far, the `iOS` part doesn't (the "run" button in run configurations under the newly created iPhone configuration is greyed out).

In its preferences `Titanium` automatically found the `iOS SDK Home` path, developer certificates are present, as are provisioning profiles. The device is also registered (I can build, compile and install `iOS` apps on an actual device using the latest `Xcode Version 4.6.2 (4H1003)` on 64-bit Mac OS X 10.8.3). The `Xcode iOS` emulator also works fine.

I also tried to create a new configuration under `iOS` Application Installer but there is a red x in front of "select development certificate" and I can not change anything. The same goes for "select provisioning profile". When I click "browse" to select a project, the list is empty.

Any ideas, anyone? :-)

Kind regards,

Pieter Vloem